# using only AWS Cognito + mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, authentication

Are you able to only use AWS Cognito for authentication or do you have to use other AWS services? I've created an app using node.js, express, vue.js and mysql. And I want to add a third party authentication service and I seen that AWS offers authentication (cognito)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, in a project I used aws cognito for authentication only. Now they have a very good documentation with a newer version of cognito called amplify, https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/authentication

Comment: So just to be clear, If you want you can only use the authentication and connect it to any type of database?

Comment: Yap, that's exactly it, I used a mysql DB with aws just for authentication.

Comment: If you have any documentation that you used please share! I would gladly appreciate it

Comment: During this weekend I will try to find something, if not, in the link I provided there's plenty of examples. In the aws site there are some tricks, after you create the user pool, you can't change the attributes of a user, don't select the option related with client secret or cliente id, something like that, because it has some problems. The SMS authentication system has some problems in the last days of the month due to payments atleast for me but despite that, I works well. If anything comes up, I will tell you

Comment: Pedro Silva can you clarify where the integration with Amplify and the MYSQL database happens? I've got an existing user table in MYSQL and would like to use Amplify if a user forgets their password.